# Handling back press when using fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, back, navigation-drawer

I am using Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer in my application and Fragments are used in the app instead of Activities.
When I open the drawer, click on an item a Fragment appears. I move from one fragment to another fragment using the following code:

```
Fragment fragment = null;
fragment = new GalleryFragment(selectetdMainMenu.getCategoryID());
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    ft.addToBackStack("menuFrag");
                    ft.add(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "menuFrag");
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                    ft.commit();
```

In this way I can go from one fragment to another but I fail to come to the previous fragment on back button press. I managed to come up with this code to handle back press in MainActivity where Drawer is Initialized:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Fragment fragment_byTag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("menuFrag");
        Fragment menuFragment_by_tag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("galleryFrag");
        Fragment commentsFrag_by_tag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("commentsFrag");
        Fragment dealDetail = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("promoFrag");
            if(commentsFrag_by_tag != null){
                if (commentsFrag_by_tag.isVisible()) {
                    Log.e("comments back  ", " clicked");
                    //menuDetailsFrag.onBackPressed();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(commentsFrag_by_tag).commit();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(menuFragment_by_tag).commit();
                }
            }else if(menuFragment_by_tag.isVisible()){
                Log.e("menu back  ", " clicked");
                menuDetailsFrag.onBackPressed();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(menuFragment_by_tag).commit();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().show(fragment_byTag).commit();
            }
        }



    return false;
}
```

This works at times but fails most of the time. I would greatly appreciate if a better way to navigate back can be shown.

Comment: Check this one out ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-intents-in-fragment

Comment: add this `ft.addToBackStack(null);ft.commit();` add the fragments to the backstack and pop them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550420/how-to-handle-back-event-in-drawer-list-fragment-in-android-activity/22550460#22550460

Comment: @Raghunandan. The easiest solution I found is yours.

Comment: I know this post is old but see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430033/3999826

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I usually set an `onKeyListener` to the `View` in `onResume`. From what I learned you have to take care to set `setFocusableInTouchMode()` and `requestFocus` on the `View`.

This is a sample of what I use for this purpose:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {

    super.onResume();

    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                // handle back button

                return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: where do I place this code? fragment or main activity>

Comment: This worked. I added getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(); to handle back press.

Comment: what is the reason for having keyevent inside onresume?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you could also put it in `onCreateView`

Comment: @super-qua, superb solution for fragment

Comment: @super-qua Simple and nice solution works fine.. no need to have interface to identify back pressed..thank you

Comment: This will stop working if you have a child view within the fragment that can gain focus. For example if you have a "list state" and "edit state" in the fragment, you go into the "edit state" that has an `EditText` within it, select the `EditText`, the main view will lose focus and the `onKey()` will stop functioning unless you manually regain focus of the base view.

Comment: Imho if a child view like an EditText holds the focus, you don't want the fragment to handle the back press but the EditText itself since the context of the back press is relevant. So this is a perfectly fine behaviour

Comment: great to hear that @bhavikshah28

Comment: I have added the same code inside onResume method but it is calling again and again top fragment on fragment backstack.

Comment: I know this post is old. but see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430033/3999826

Answer (score 5):

Try these methods. To me, the most useful solution is as follows:

In MainActivity:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.gif_contents, gifPageTwoFragment, "gifPageTwoFragment").addToBackStack("gifPageTwoFragment").commit();
```

In GifPageTwoFragment:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    Log.e("gif--","fragment back key is clicked");
                    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack("gifPageTwoFragment", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your oncreateView() method you need to write this code and in KEYCODE_BACk condition you can write whatever the functionality you want

```
   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, container, false);
    //Back pressed Logic for fragment
    v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    v.requestFocus();
    v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                    getActivity().finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This was perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

use this (in kotlin)

```
activity?.onBackPressedDispatcher?.addCallback(this, object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
    override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
        // in here you can do logic when backPress is clicked
    }
})
```

i think this is the most elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)   {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


            Fragment NameofFragment = new NameofFragment;

            FragmentTransaction  transaction=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container,NameofFragment);

            transaction.commit();

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});

return view;
```